# Cannot create/access SSRS server on local system

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I installed a full version of SQL server 2008 R2 developer with SSIS, SSRS, SSAS. I started the SSRS service in windows. No matter which server name I try, I get the error Unable to connect to the report server ZZZ. In management studio, I can see SQl servers, Integration Server but no Report server. It looks like I need to create one so that I can learn SSRS. How do I do this ?

The error photo -

[image]

Could this have something to do with the SS2012 BI stack that I have also installed ?

Comment: Post the SQL Server Configuration page. SQL Server usually installs with an instance name, and I don't see one on you server connection.

Comment: @KRichard - I opened Sql Server Config manager. SQL server services node says "the remote procedure call failed". I know and I saw that the name of my SQL server instance is SQLSERVER2008.

Comment: You need to provide the actual `Machine Name` in Server name section instead of the `Local` or `.`.

Comment: @M.Ali - How do I find out the actual machine name ? I tried to copy the name from sql server - myUser\myPc and it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Goto --> MyComputer -->  RIGHT Click --> Properties --> look for Computer name. Alternatively go to SSMS connect to server and Execute `SELECT @@SERVERNAME` ,, it will return the `ServerName\InstanceName` use that server name in your server name section and drop down will be populated will all the available instances of sql server for that server.

Comment: @M.Ali - The SQL only gives me server name and not instance name. So, I still get the error in the pic.

Comment: Now that you know the instance, you should connect using that. You do not need to list the machine name if it is local. In the server name textbox enter: (local)\SQLSERVER2008

Comment: @KRichard - Unable to connect to local)\SQLSERVER2008. Could this have something to do with the SS2012 BI stack that I have also installed  ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your own local machine is a server, enter localhost and NOT local or (local). After that at least I got a better error - no report servers were found. link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/050011a9-8600-4e4f-9455-706469c9b520/no-report-servers-were-found-on-the-specified-machine-sql-server-2005-and-windows-server-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices

Next, I tried this -

Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager Make sure the "Reporting Service" service is listed in the service list, and it is running. Nothing found. I saw an error - the remote procedure call failed 0x800706be, under the SQL server services node.

I finally decided that I had to reinstall the whole BI stack. Perhaps you can save yourself the headache by uninstalling SSRS only and reinstalling it. If you don't have
the installation files, you're probably screwed.

The link I used - http://www.soheib.com/technical-knowledge/how-to-install-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-on-a-virtual-machine/

On the install window, choose whatever options you want till you get to this screen -

[image]

14) Next is server configuration which asks you to associate an Account to use for the Reporting Services. I am choosing SYSTEM (You can also create a separate account), 
click Next:

[image]

15) Choose Install, but do not configure the report server and click Next:

[image]

Finally, follow all the steps to complete the installation yourself.

**NOTE -** If you have SS2012 also in your system like I did, then you will continue to get the error 0x800706be I mentioned above. To fix that you MUST upgrade SS2008 to 
Service Pack 1 or higher.